# Moment js is not working with JSON in React Native

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native

This is my JSON:

```
orders:[{
   "buyerEmail": "unknow@gmail.com",
   "profile_name_ru": "ПРЕДПРИНИМАТЬ",
   "bin": "20940010947",
   "date_time": "15.10.2019 10:39:27"
   }
 ]
```

I am getting date_time and outputing it on React Native app  like this.

```
<View>
 <Text>{orders.dateTime}</Text>
</View>
```

It is showing. 
But if I am using Moment.js.I am getting Invalid date.

```
render(){   
    const ed = (order.dateTime);
    const check = moment(new Date(ed)).format("DD.MM.YYYY, HH:MM");
   return (
        <View>
           <Text>{check}</Text>
         </View>
    )    
}
```

Can anybody tell why I am getting an invalid date?

Comment: try `"DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moment was working .But your time string was wrong .You need to change the date format string to `YYYY-MM-DD` or else mention the format on moment initiate

> `MM`- month
>
> `mm`-  minutes
>
> `hh`- 12 hrs
>
> `HH`- 24 hrs

```js
let str = '15.10.2019 10:39:27';

console.log(new Date(str)) //check this its return null

//so need to mention format while initialize
console.log(moment(str,'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss').format('DD.MM.YYYY, hh:mm A'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your parsing format is incorrect. Change to:

```
moment("15.10.2019 10:39:27", "DD.MM.YYYY h:mm:ss");
```

Check the parsing [docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/)